# Free space in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I had a problem with free space when developing the design and any attempts to remove it do not help

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG5sH.png)

[Problem with a free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qplvu.png)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:background="@color/egovcolorblue"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="171dp"
            android:text="Name Surname"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userIIN"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:text="ИИН: 123456789123"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="104dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to replace FrameLayout with ConstraintLayout and snap them to the sides, but it didn't help, this is the first time I've encountered this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I noticed that the layout MainActivity adds this free space, but I haven't figured it out yet. I used the standard Bottom Navigation template from Android Studio slightly changing them

Comment: Can share your activity's layout file? I suspect, your main activity is adding some space to the fragment's view.

Comment: you're right, the mainactivity layout itself adds this free space, but I haven't figured it out myself yet and I added mainactivity layout xml

Comment: android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" 
This is the issue. Remove this line and everything will look good.